# Netbeans hotkey to turn off highlighted search text?

Tags: php, search, netbeans, highlight, hotkeys

I've googled this question but found none.

Please share if you know how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 7.0: Tools -> Options -> Keymap -> 'Toggle Highlight Search'. Mine is Alt+Shift+H.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken what you are looking for it Alt+Shift+H

Comment: Yeah, that's what it is. Thank you! Can't believe such thing not easily via google

Comment: That's actually where I found it when I was asking myself the same question last week. Took a lot of digging and I stumbled upon it in some posts down in some obscure forum post. Sometimes I think there is some black magic involved in google searches :P