# Hotkey for temporary turning off variable usage highlight in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, editor

After my cursor/carret is placed on a variable, its usage in the code is highlighted automatically as in the snapshot below. It distracts me. I want to temporary turn it off.

I search for this and got the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657064/netbeans-hotkey-to-turn-off-highlighted-search-text) but it relates to the `search text`.
I'm looking for turning it off for `variable usage`.

What is the hotkey to temporary turn off highlight for variable usage?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From checking the keymap and doing a quick web search, there doesn't currently seem to be a hotkey.

However, you can toggle it in the options:

(7.0) Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Mark Occurrences.

To get a hotkey for this, you can [request it](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) or [implement it yourself](https://netbeans.org/community/contribute/code.html).

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling. I'll post a new request there. In the mean time, I'll turn it off then though I love the feature.